# Referencing one variable in function exports both

Tags: powershell

The following script:

```
cls
function test_me([string]$testVar, $my_array)
{
    Write-Host $testVar
}

$test_array = "a","b"
test_me "z", $test_array
```

Produces the following result:

```
z System.Object[]
```

I only want to reference $testVar

Why is *System.Object[]* getting returned to the Write-Host?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This error is probably as old as PowerShell...
You call function like method, and it won't work like that, try this instead:

```
test_me 'z' $test_array
```

HTH
Bartek